# Enable C# 7 support in VSTS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, roslyn, c#-7.0

It appears that VSTS does not support C# 7, as I'm getting a build error which would would indicate the C# 6 compiler is being used. How do I enable C# 7, or what am I doing wrong? I'm using Visual Studio 2017, targeting .NET 4.6.1.

I would rather not have to revert C# 7 changes I've added if possible. As can be seen in the screenshot of Visual Studio and the console in VSTS, there is a difference in the version of C# in use.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK so it turns out that it was a simple fix, it was a counter-intuitive option in the UI. There's actually 2 places that configure the version of Visual Studio being used in VSTS. It needs to be set to `Visual Studio 2017` or `Latest` and `Hosted VS2017`. Why there are 2 options is not very clear.

[image]

Comment: see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted the "latest" version installed on the normal hosted agent is 2015. If you choose 2017 on it and check your build log you will see a warning saying it could not find 2017 and it fell back to the highest it could find (2015).